# OpenGL rotation around an object while doing self rotation

Tags: opengl, rotation

I am trying to simulate a planet system in OpenGL using the programmable pipeline. Suppose now I have a planet A, whose centroid is `planet_A_FixedPoint` and a planet C, whose centroid is `planet_C_FixedPoint`. I want to let planet C rotate around planet A with rotation axis = `normalize(planet_A_FixedPoint)` and at the same time rotate around its own center with rotation axis = `(0,1,0)`. I came up with the following codes but it didn't seem to work.

```
glm::mat4 rotateAroundPlanetA = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), planet_A_FixedPoint) * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), degree, normalize(planet_A_FixedPoint)) \
    * glm::translate(glm::mat4(), -planet_A_FixedPoint);
planet_C_M_Matrix = rotateAroundPlanetA * planet_C_M_Matrix;
glm::vec4 tempFixedPoint = rotateAroundPlanetA * glm::vec4(planet_C_FixedPoint, 1.0f);
planet_C_FixedPoint = vec3(tempFixedPoint.x, tempFixedPoint.y, tempFixedPoint.z);
glm::mat4 rotateAroundPlanetC = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), planet_C_FixedPoint) * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), degree, vec3(0, 1, 0)) \
    * glm::translate(glm::mat4(), -planet_C_FixedPoint);
planet_C_M_Matrix = rotateAroundPlanetC * planet_C_M_Matrix;
```

The achieved effect of the above codes is that planet C rotate around itself and rotate around the normalize(XA, YA, ZA) axis, but it does not align with the origin of planet A (XA, YA, ZA).

Can anyone tell me where I was wrong?

Comment: Please post your real code, the above snippet won't even compile.

Comment: Hi~I have posted my real codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you use scope operator (::) use it everywhere.
Secondly, you code has expected behavior. If you want that planet C align with the origin of planet A, then you rotation axis need to be perpendicular plane, which contain origin C and origin A.

Comment: What do you mean by perpendicular plane?

Comment: sorry, i mean "rotation axis need to be orthogonal to the plane..."

Comment: But now the problem is that planet C is rotating around the expected axis, but center at the origin (0, 0, 0). Not planetA (XA, YA, ZA)

Comment: if insert correct axis instead normalize(planet_A_FixedPoint) you code work fine for me

Comment: But how do I get a plane if I only have two points, planetA and planetC

Comment: I don't know "planet science", but we can use cross product to obtain orthogonal vector.

Comment: I don't know "planet science", but we can use cross product to obtain orthogonal vector, 
glm::vec3 vec_between_planet = glm::normalize(planet_C_FixedPoint - planet_A_FixedPoint);
helpVecotr =normalize(cross(yourotation,vec_between_planet))
final_rotation = normalize(cross(helpVector,vec_between_planet))

Comment: Sorry I am a little bit slow in 3D. What is yourotation?

Comment: it's  normalize(planet_A_FixedPoint) for you